# how to calculate overlap duration of two non-periodic time series + grouped

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series

I have two timeseries tables without fixed interval timestamps (the sample data is fixed to 10s just for simplicity).  I can't use TimeScaleDB or others at the moment and need to calculate the duration of time when each timeseries of the device table is active at the same time as the check table, at 1 second precision for a 24hr period.

I've failed miserably trying to get something to work using generateSeries to resample the data to 1s and fill in the blanks, nothing is quite right, and when it looks like it is, postgres just disappears forever or pgadmin crashes.

If I were do program in a C type lanuguage I would want to have two cursors for the each table row, and loop through the entire table in one pass.  Surely we can do that here?

Diagram of the problem:

[image: StateDiagram]

Example table:

```
DeviceOnline

  Device Id      Start                  End

( 'Device_001', '2023-07-03 11:00:00', '2023-07-03 11:00:50' ), 
( 'Device_001', '2023-07-03 11:01:10', '2023-07-03 11:01:30' ),
( 'Device_002', '2023-07-03 11:00:10', '2023-07-03 11:00:30' ),
( 'Device_002', '2023-07-03 11:01:00', '2023-07-03 11:01:20' ),
( 'Device_003', '2023-07-03 11:00:01', '2023-07-03 11:01:59' ),
( 'Device_003', '2023-07-03 11:04:00', '2023-07-03 11:05:00' ),
( 'Device_004', '2023-07-03 11:00:00', '2023-07-03 11:00:10' ),
( 'Device_004', '2023-07-03 11:00:40', '2023-07-03 11:00:50' ),

ServerOnline

( '2023-07-03 10:55:00', '2023-07-03 10:59:00' ),
( '2023-07-03 11:00:20', '2023-07-03 11:00:40' ), 
( '2023-07-03 11:01:10', '2023-07-03 11:01:40' ),
( '2023-07-03 11:02:00', '2023-07-03 11:03:00' ),


Expected Output

Device      Duration

Device_001  40s
Device_002  20s
Device_003  50s
Device_004   0s
```

[Test fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/bef45)

Comment: Not quite following your example, but I suspect the solution is going to involve [Range types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) and the intersection of ranges as shown here [Range operators/functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html).

Comment: FYI, I have to believe the second timestamp in each record is `2023-07-03 ...` not `2021-07-03 ...`.  A quick and dirty example: `select tsrange('2023-07-03 11:00:00', '2023-07-03 11:00:50') * tsrange('2023-07-03 11:00:20', '2023-07-03 11:00:40'); ["2023-07-03 11:00:20","2023-07-03 11:00:40")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tsrange` type makes this simple.

BTW, are you really using PostgreSQL 9.6?

```
select deviceid, 
       sum(upper(overlap) - lower(overlap)) as overlap_time
  from (select d.deviceid, 
               tsrange(d.starttime, d.endtime) 
                 * tsrange(s.starttime, s.endtime) as overlap 
          from devicestatus d
               join serverstatus s
                 on tsrange(d.starttime, d.endtime) 
                      && tsrange(s.starttime, s.endtime)) o
 group by deviceid;
```

Updated [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2595d/3)

Comment: You are an absolute magician.  SQL hurts my brain, I'm too procedural...   That query looks elegant next to my attempts.  Thank you!

No we'd never use 9.6...   Still on 9.3.4    I have got a development instance upgraded to v15 and no issues, so no Idea why the team responsible have not been updating it...